# Как в MySQL вывести все элементы которые были созданы последовательно в течении заданного времени, например 30 секунд?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица  `products` у которого есть столбец `created_at`  нужно вывести все продукты
которые были созданы последовательно в течении  30 секунд,

То есть

```
product1   2020-06-02 14:20:5
product2   2020-06-02 15:00:5
product3   2020-06-02 15:00:10
product4   2020-06-02 15:00:20
product5   2020-06-02 15:00:40

product6   2020-06-02 15:02:45
product7   2020-06-02 15:03:50
```

SQL код должен вывести только 
(OUTPUT)

```
product2   2020-06-02 15:00:5
product3   2020-06-02 15:00:10
product4   2020-06-02 15:00:20
product5   2020-06-02 15:00:40
```

Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: возьмите текущее время, отнимите от нее 30 секунд. выберите те строки где больше. в чем сложность?

Comment: или я не правильно понял условие, или же вот это ```product5   2020-06-02 15:00:40``` не должно попасть в выборку

Comment: @teran в вопросе не сказано "за ПОСЛЕДНИЕ" 30 секунд, а вообще которые раньше были созданы в интервале 30 секунд

Comment: ```select * from table where created_at>=@date and created_at<DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL 30 SECOND)```

Comment: Если у вас задача в том, чтобы вывести продукты, к которых интервал с соседней менее 30 секунд, то так и пишите вопрос.

Comment: @teran  да задача в этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM products t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM products t2
               WHERE t1.created_at BETWEEN t2.created_at - INTERVAL 30 SECOND
                                       AND t2.created_at + INTERVAL 30 SECOND
                 AND t1.created_at != t2.created_at )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b234f0a6baec66662439563b660da96)

Comment: да код медленный но работает, как я понял он  работает   только с прямыми соседями и  не сможет вывести заданный  OUTPUT пример из вопроса

Comment: @a_mine так он это и выводит

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis  да он может это вывести потому что 
+- 30 секунд   это  получается интервал 60 секунд  если взять +-15 секунд вряд ли сработает

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis  и по коду видно что он работает только с прямыми соседями

Comment: Вы сами подтвердили, что задача - ```вывести продукты, у которых интервал с соседней менее 30 секунд```. Именно это и делает запрос

Comment: @ о каких прямых соседях речь? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aec34e3cbec07dc269bde53c1ae87968

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis интервал больше 30 секунд  
[-30 , + 30]  = 60 секунд за счет этого вывод получается таким как был задан в вопросе

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=14a93d4db122bf73eb02704350bcdf64
последний элемент не должен выводится

Comment: @a_mine почему он не должен выводится, если у него с product6 интервал 2 секунды?

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis  минуты разные

Comment: Проверьте внимательно. 15:02:45 у product6 и 15:02:43 у product27

Comment: @a_mine что за условия еще про минуты?

Comment: условие `t1.created_at != t2.created_at )` надо заменить на `t1.id != t2.id` ну или нечто с ключом.

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis   да я сравнивал  с предыдущим и не заметил product6,
видимо работает если не будет другого ответа или возражения приму как правильный

Comment: @a_mine *он работает только с прямыми соседями и не сможет вывести заданный OUTPUT пример из вопроса* Вообще-то если "дальний" сосед укладывается в полминуты - то "ближний" в них укладывается стопудово... а вот наоборот уже вряд ли. *да код медленный* Ну если Вы всё-таки укажете версию своего MySQL, то, возможно, получите ещё одно, и, вероятно, более быстрое, решение - или нет, в зависимости от версии.

Comment: @Akina   MySQL   version    5.5.60

Comment: @a_mine Не, тогда почти безнадёжно... разве что попробовать использовать UDV... но это будет фулскан плюс кэширование подзапроса по всей таблице.